# How to calculate the max and min value in one query for multiple result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the `Min` and `Max` attendance for a specific `venue`, my idea is get all the venues available in the `venue` table, and then iterate through of it, anyway, this is not a simple solution, so I'm wondering if is possible calculate the `Min` and `Max` attendance directly in one query for multiple venues.

Suppose that in the table `match` there are these records:

```
id | venue_id | venue_attendance |
 1      5             1800
 2      5             2000
 3      6             500
 4      6             750
```

the query should return this result:

```
{
   venue_id: 5, 
   min_attendance: 1800,
   max_attendance: 2000
},
{
   venue_id: 6, 
   min_attendance: 500,
   max_attendance: 750
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, just use `MIN` and `MAX` with `group by` by `venue_id` column.

```
SELECT venue_id,
       MIN(venue_attendance) as min_attendance,
       MAX(venue_attendance) as max_attendance
FROM `match`
GROUP BY venue_id
```

SQLfildde:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d7cd3/4

Comment: Thanks this works +1, I can do this also for calculate the avg?